# Why did running Maven clean ruin my application

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using SpringToolSuite4 and when I ran Maven clean it said it was successful, but when I try running it as a java application it now says

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.main.StartApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.main.StartApplication
```

Just wondering why maven clean ruined my application

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apolis</groupId>
  <artifactId>Oct14</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you provide pom.xml configuration?

Comment: Ok I edited it in

Comment: If you are running a project using `java -jar application.jar` Then you need to configure https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/ with mainClass

Comment: If you are running the project from Eclipse, Maven may have built your output into the local MAVEN_HOME, rather than your project's Build Path's output folder, which is where Eclipse expects the class files to go. In that case, you need to Clean and rebuild from the Project menu.